# Configuring Proxy setup with Spring Security OAuth2RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, proxy, spring-security-oauth2

I am attempting to setup a connection to github for a basic OAuth2 flow behind a corporate proxy.  The below code keeps receiving an Unknown Host exception.  Note this code is running on a simple Zuul Proxy calling two separate restful webservices that just return "hello world".

Version info: Spring Boot 1.4.2.Release

Dependencies: spring-boot-starter-web, spring-cloud-starter-zuul, spring-cloud-starter-security, spring-security-oauth, org.apache.httpcomponents

```
@EnableOAuth2Sso
@EnableZuulProxy
@RestController
@SpringBootApplication
public class CipeApiGatewayApplication extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter implements UserInfoRestTemplateCustomizer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CipeApiGatewayApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Value("${:myUserName}")
    String proxyUser;

    @Value("${:myEpicPassword}")
    String proxyPassword;

    @Value("${:proxy.fun.com}")
    String proxyHost;

    @Value("${:8080}")
    int proxyPort;

    @RequestMapping("/user")
    public Principal user(Principal principal) {
        return principal;
    }

    //Just does some logging
    @Bean
    public SimpleFilter simpleFilter() {
        return new SimpleFilter();
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        //@formatter:off
        http
            .antMatcher("/**")
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/login**", "/webjars/**")
                .permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
            .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll();
        //@formatter:on
    }

    @Override
    public void customize(OAuth2RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        // Instanciate a new http client with proxy configuration, and bypass SSL Certificate verification
        CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        credentialsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, new UsernamePasswordCredentials(proxyUser, proxyPassword));

        HttpClientBuilder httpClientBuilder = null;
        try {
            httpClientBuilder = HttpClients.custom()
                    .setProxy(new HttpHost(proxyHost, proxyPort))
                    .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
                    .setSSLHostnameVerifier(new NoopHostnameVerifier())
                    .setSSLContext(new SSLContextBuilder().loadTrustMaterial(null, (x509Certificates, s) -> true)
                            .build());
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // requestFactory
        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClientBuilder.build());
        ClientCredentialsAccessTokenProvider clientCredentialsAccessTokenProvider = new ClientCredentialsAccessTokenProvider();
        clientCredentialsAccessTokenProvider.setRequestFactory(requestFactory);

        // accessTokenProvider
        AccessTokenProvider accessTokenProvider = new AccessTokenProviderChain(Arrays.<AccessTokenProvider> asList(
                new AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider(), new ImplicitAccessTokenProvider(),
                new ResourceOwnerPasswordAccessTokenProvider(), clientCredentialsAccessTokenProvider));

        restTemplate.setAccessTokenProvider(accessTokenProvider);
    }
}
```

stack trace:

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Could not obtain access token
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.filter.OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:107) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.12.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:121) [spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:100) [spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66) [spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) [spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214) [spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) [spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) [spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) [spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.filter.OAuth2ClientContextFilter.doFilter(OAuth2ClientContextFilter.java:60) [spring-security-oauth2-2.0.12.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:89) [spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) [spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) [spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:107) [spring-boot-actuator-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_77]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_77]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_77]
Caused by: org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.resource.OAuth2AccessDeniedException: Error requesting access token.
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.OAuth2AccessTokenSupport.retrieveToken(OAuth2AccessTokenSupport.java:145) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.12.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.grant.code.AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider.obtainAccessToken(AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider.java:209) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.12.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.AccessTokenProviderChain.obtainNewAccessTokenInternal(AccessTokenProviderChain.java:148) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.12.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.AccessTokenProviderChain.obtainAccessToken(AccessTokenProviderChain.java:121) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.12.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.acquireAccessToken(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:221) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.12.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.getAccessToken(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:173) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.12.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.filter.OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.12.RELEASE.jar:na]
    ... 60 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token": github.com; nested exception is java.net.UnknownHostException: github.com
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:633) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:588) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.OAuth2AccessTokenSupport.retrieveToken(OAuth2AccessTokenSupport.java:137) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.12.RELEASE.jar:na]
    ... 66 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: github.com
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:668) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:173) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:264) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1105) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:999) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:153) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:78) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:619) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    ... 68 common frames omitted

2017-01-23 07:33:24.627 DEBUG 14836 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] uth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter : Updated SecurityContextHolder to contain null Authentication
2017-01-23 07:33:24.627 DEBUG 14836 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] uth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter : Delegating to authentication failure handler org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler@6c1f8162
2017-01-23 07:33:24.627 DEBUG 14836 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] .a.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler : No failure URL set, sending 401 Unauthorized error
2017-01-23 07:33:24.627 DEBUG 14836 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@2b8d30eb
2017-01-23 07:33:24.627 DEBUG 14836 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
2017-01-23 07:33:24.628 DEBUG 14836 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

Comment: Still having issues with this :(  Any ideas?

Comment: Facing same issue, could NOT bypass corporate proxy resulting: `Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Sun Feb 04 09:48:50 IST 2018
There was an unexpected error (type=Unauthorized, status=401).
Authentication Failed: Could not obtain access token`

Comment: anyone found solution for this?